# Writing a oracle stored procedure to generate a unique serial number?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, generator, serial-number

I need to generate a unique serial number in our web application.

I have created a table called SerialNumber which will have only one row. In the begining it will have value like '0000000000' ten times zero. This will be incremented by one every time a serial number needs to be generated.

e.g. 0000000001,  0000000002 and so on.

I have kept the column datatype as Integer which stores values as 0, 1, 2 etc and not as 0000000001. I want the serial number to be ten digits only with zeros appended at the begining.

Please help me to write the stored proc for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select to_char(<column-value>, 'FM0000000000') from serialNumber;
```

I don't know what's *behind* your requirement, but most probably, you are better served with a [sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/schemaob.htm#CNCPT611). Using a table to generate unique ids is usually a poor choice that should be reviewed.

As for a stored procedure along with a *sequence*, a basic frame to build upon could be:

#### The sequence:

```
create sequence serial_number_seq;
```

#### The stored procedure (actually: a function)

```
create or replace function next_serial_number return varchar2 as

       serial_number_ number;
       MAX_SR_NO number;
begin

       select serial_number_seq.nextval into serial_number_ from DUAL;

       Select MAX(sr_no) INTO MAX_SR_NO from serialNumber;

       serial_number_ := GREATEST(serial_number_, MAX_SR_NO); 

       return to_char(serial_number_, 'FM0000000000');

end    next_serial_number;
/
```

#### testing

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(next_serial_number);
  dbms_output.put_line(next_serial_number);
  dbms_output.put_line(next_serial_number);
  dbms_output.put_line(next_serial_number);
  dbms_output.put_line(next_serial_number);
  dbms_output.put_line(next_serial_number);
-- in the place where you use the serial number the greatest 
--  of inserted value from external system or sequence value will be used
 final_value:= next_serial_number;
end;
/
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out to use a sequence.  Doing this from a table will cause a bottleneck if your app gets busy.

Comment: @René Nyffenegger. I may have records inserted into the table with serial numbers generated from some external source. In that case I will also need to check if the serial number being generated by function does not match with any of the existing serial numbers in system. And this is beyond my control as we will definitely have sn. from other sources. I dont have any other option than to check in db. How do I check that in function?

Comment: @Ashish what ever comes from the external source you can store in table and then compare this value against the one generated in the function provided by René Nyffenegger

Comment: @psaraj12. So I will have to getNewSerial(), check in db if exist getNewSerial(), check in db if exist , getNewSerial check in db if not exist return. But How do I implement this in my stopred procedure?

Comment: @psaraj12. Sorry but I could not find it? Where have you put it?

Comment: @Ashish you can check the usage of MAX_SR_NO and final_value in the blocks of answer provided

Comment: @Ashish Sorry I have edited René Nyffenegger answer which has to be peer reviewed

Comment: @Ashish: I didn't know I could/had to peer review edited answers. But it's done now.

Comment: @René Nyffenegger. Hi. The other table will have values like 0000000002, 0000000003, 0000000006, 0000000008, 1100000002, 1100000003 etc. very random. If our function creates value like 0000000008 how does the above procedure work in that case. because the other system is very unpredictable in generating serial numbers. It may already have created few serial numbers in table which are yet to be created by our sequence. In that case this MAX thing will not work.

Comment: I guess you should open a new question specifically addressing your problem. It's definitely not in the realm of this question to adress this. In the other question you should then define what *unpredictable* is, what you expect from the system and what you try to achieve.

Comment: @Ashish In your question you said  the serial number table will be incremented by one every time a serial number needs to be generated but now your comment is completely different

Answer (score 3):

Please use

```
lpad(serial_no, 10, '0');
```

more information at

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lpad.php

and it is also better to use sequence in oracle other than storing in table

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php